# How to create function for reserved xml characters in sql

Tags: xml, character, oracle-sqldeveloper, reserved

Please any one help for me to create function for reserved XML Character in SQL.
The below I've tried the below function but it is not working for me.

```
function escape_char(p_text varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
     return (replace(p_text, '<','&lt;'));
     return (replace(p_text, '>','&gt;'));
     return (replace(p_text, '&','&amp;'));
     return (replace(p_text, '''','&apos;'));
     return (replace(p_text, '"','&quot;'));
end;
```

Comment: Please edit & add a tag for the specific Database you are using

Comment: yes, added. i'm using SQL

Comment: Yes, but what platform - MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server ... each is different.

Comment: Yep added. please clarify.. to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a `RETURN` in a function, the function will return some value and end; this way, in your function, only the first `replace` will be run, and the code below will never be executed.

This is a simple way to edit it:

```
create or replace function escape_char(p_text varchar2) return varchar2 is
    vRetVal     varchar2(100);
begin
     vRetVal := replace(p_text, '&','&amp;');
     vRetVal := replace(vRetVal, '<','&lt;'); 
     vRetVal := replace(vRetVal, '>','&gt;');
     vRetVal := replace(vRetVal, '''','&apos;');
     vRetVal := replace(vRetVal, '"','&quot;');
     --
     return vRetVal;
end;
```

Comment: thank you.. but its not working... its not replaced in my output.....please help me

Comment: What do you mean with not working? If I create this procedure and run it, I see all the substitutions you need. What is your issue?

Comment: and another thing " vRetVal := replace(vRetVal, '&','&amp;');" replacing
vRetVal := replace(p_text, '<','&lt;'); 
     vRetVal := replace(vRetVal, '>','&gt;');
     vRetVal := replace(vRetVal, '''','&apos;');
     vRetVal := replace(vRetVal, '"','&quot;');  ....which means output of <> is showing like &amp;lt;&amp;gt;

Comment: You're right, the best way is to replace the `&` first